# How to add subtitle in Video using Ffmpeg Command

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I m executing below command and getting **Stream #0:0: Subtitle: unknown_codec
 (codec unknown_codec) not found for output stream #0:0** 
FFmpeg command:

```
final String demoVideoPath =   "/sdcard/b.mp4";
final String subTitlePath="/sdcard/srtf.srt";
String ffmpegCommand[] = { "ffmpeg", "-i", demoVideoPath, "-i", subTitlePath,
                        "-map","1", "-c", "copy","-strict", "experimental","-c:v","mpeg","-crf","23","-preset","veryfast",
                          "/sdcard/output.avi" };
```

LogCat

```
 Shellout[srt @ 0xc03930] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
 ShelloutInput #1, srt, from '/sdcard/srtf.srt':
Shellout  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
 Shellout    Stream #1:0: Subtitle: srt
 ShelloutPlease use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
 ShelloutOutput #0, avi, to '/sdcard/output.avi':
Shellout  Metadata:
 Shellout    major_brand     : isom
Shellout    minor_version   : 512
 Shellout    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41

Shellout    creation_time   : 2013-12-20 11:33:07
Shellout    encoder         : Lavf51.12.1
 Shellout    Stream #0:0: Subtitle: unknown_codec
 ShelloutStream mapping:
Shellout  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (srt -> ?)
ShelloutEncoder (codec unknown_codec) not found for output stream #0:0
```

How to handle unknown_codec error.

Comment: You should show your complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: @lordNeckbeard -Check this log i haved added logs

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the complete output.